# Moving Lemma for Intersection Calculation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

My question refers to following argument in the proof of a statement in Hartshornes AG (chapter V, p 370):

[image]

We consider the fiber $f= \pi^{-1}(b)$ of a closed point $b$.

How he argue here with "distinct" fibers? Is here used implicitely something like "moving lemma", such that to calculate the self intersectivion one shifts $f$ to another disjunct fiber?

Why it can be done or why does it work here? Wikis description of moving lemma doen't help me to decide why it is here possible.

Are all fibers linear equivalent such that they can be shifted without changing intersection number?

Or is here used the property that $f$ is a Cartier divisor with corresponding ample invertible sheaf such that every global section of it can "replace" $f$ for calculation?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the moving lemma here. One approach is to find other points which will be linearly equivalent to $b$, or at least some multiple of $b$.

In particular, by Riemann-Roch (or exercise 4.1.2 in Hartshorne) there exists a rational function $f\in k(C)$ such that $\mathrm{div}(f) = \sum n_ip_i - nb$, where $n_i \ge 0$ and for some $n>0$.  In particular we have that $nb \sim n_ip_i \in \mathrm{Pic}(C)$ .

It then follows that $n \pi^{-1}(b) \sim \sum n_i \pi^{-1}(p_i)$ (pullback $\mathrm{div}(f)$ and check that its divisor is $n \pi^{-1}(b) -\sum n_i \pi^{-1}(p_i)$). In particular, you see that $nf$ is linearly equivalent to $\sum n_i f_i$, where $f_i$ doesn't intersect $f$. So now you have $n^2f^2 = nf (\sum n_if_i) = 0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer. It makes of course the idea clearer, but one step isn't obviously to me: How Riemann-Roch implies the existence of such a $f$ with $\mathrm{div}(f) = \sum n_ip_i - nb$? Hartshornes version of it just describes a relation of a divisor (here for example a fiber) with canonical divisor $K$. Could you explain why RR provides such $f$?

Comment: @KarlPeter Consider the divisor $D = nb$. RR tells you that $h^0(D) - h^0(K-D) = \deg D - g + 1$, hence $h^0(D) = h^0(K-D) + \deg D - g + 1$. So you see that if $n$ is very big, then the right hand side is positive. Now recall that $h^0(D) = \{f\in K(C): div(f) + D \ge 0 \}$. So if the dimension of this is bigger than $1$, this implies that there exists $f\in k(C)$ where $f$ has a pole at $b$. Along with the fact that any map $f:C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ has the same number of zeros and poles you get the claim.